# Logcat garbage collector message

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-logcat

I want to monitor my memory usage. My Logcat is always printing this message which is the easiest way for me to view my memory usage. Does K mean Kilobytes, or Kilobits, in this instance? And does this message state that I am using 10981K of memory?

```
01-20 16:37:56.007: D/dalvikvm(11392): GC_CONCURRENT freed 418K, 63% free 10981K/28999K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 18ms
```

Thanks

Comment: This should answer all your questions: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#LogMessages and yes KB stands for Kilobytes not Kilobits

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin Thanks. I know KB is Kilobytes, but Logcat says K. I assume you meant to say K means Kilobytes? Cheers

Comment: Yes that's what I meant to say